# Issue Running E2E test with Protractor

Tags: git, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I branched out from a project in git, the application compile but it does not run telling me that I'm missing some stuff, that I'm not sure I understand. and btw. I'm very new to git.

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodr               iver-v0.11.1-win64.zip'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
    at Function.FileManager.toDownload\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\files\file_man               ager.js:174:35)
    at updateBinary (...\node_modules\protr               actor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cmds\update.js:164:32)
    at Program.update [as runMethod] (...\n            ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cmds\update.js:1               27:9)
    at Program.run (...\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdrivermanager\built\lib\cli\programs.js:60:14)
    at Object. (...\node_modules               \protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\webdriver.js:25:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)

Comment: Have you tried running `webdriver-manager update`?

Comment: I tried, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Th solution was to delete "node-modules" folder then run "npm install" that actually solved the problem.